# Why is this PHP comparison failing?

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare a defined code against a set of blocked country codes.  In the following example the country code is getting caught in my if block:

```
$country_code = 'US';

if ($country_code == ("NG" || "RO" || "VN" || "GH" || "SN" || "TN" || "IN" || "ID" || "KE" || "CN" || "CI" || "ZA" || "DZ" || "RU")) {
    print "COUNTRY CODE: $country_code<br>";
}
```

I see this for my results"

```
COUNTRY CODE: US
```

I wouldn't expect 'US' to get caught...what am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are doing is `OR`-ing strings together.  Since non-empty strings converted to boolean values are true, this evaluates to the following:

```
$country_code == true
```

Since `$country_code` is also a non-empty string, that also evaluates to `true`:

```
true == true
```

Thus, you get `TRUE`.

To solve your problem, you need to do what Pekka suggests:

```
if (in_array($country_code, array('NG', 'RO', etc.)))
```

See also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: ahhh...too much time with perl I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot chain together `||` in this way and get the result you expect.  It will aways return TRUE since any non-empty string evaluates to true.  Since the operand on the left of `==` is compared to the entire operand on the right, You are in effect saying:

```
if ($country_code == (TRUE ||TRUE||TRUE||TRUE||TRUE...);
```

While it would be valid to do something like the following, it gets out of hand:

```
if ($country_code == "N" || $country_code == "RO" || $country_code == "VN" ...)
```

Instead, use `in_array()`;

```
$countries = array("NG","RO","VN","GH",...);
if (in_array($country_code, $countries) {
  print "COUNTRY CODE: $country_code<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do this

```
$country_code = 'US';

if (in_array($country_code, array("NG", "RO", "VN", "GH", "SN", "TN", "IN", "ID", "KE", "CN", "CI", "ZA", "DZ", "RU")) {
    print "COUNTRY CODE: $country_code<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
("NG" || "RO" || "VN" || "GH" || "SN" || "TN" || "IN" || "ID" || "KE" || "CN" || "CI" || "ZA" || "DZ" || "RU")
```

is actually a boolean test which says "If any of these evaluate to true then true". Since non empty strings are true then this is true. Similarly "US" will be treated as true. So simplifying the statement we get:
if(true == true).

Try using an array and the `in_array` function instead.

Comment: +1 for in the in_array function, that's a better test then the band of ORs that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot simpler if done this way.

```
$codes = array("NG", "RO", "VN");

$search = array_search("NG");
if($search) {
    echo $codes[$search];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$country_code = 'US';
```

Here your setting the `$country_code`.

```
if ($country_code == ("NG" || "RO" || "VN" || "GH" || "SN" || "TN" || "IN" || "ID" || "KE" || "CN" || "CI" || "ZA" || "DZ" || "RU")) {
```

Here your evaluating `$country_code` against nothing really, but because it's all non-empty strings they to evaluate to `TRUE`, and because `$country_code` is a non-empty string, it also evaluates to `TRUE`.

```
    print "COUNTRY CODE: $country_code<br>";
```

Here your printing `$country_code` that you set in your first line.

```
}
```

What you want is something like this

```
if (
    $country_code == "NG" ||
    $country_code == "RO" ||
    $country_code == "VN" ||
    $country_code == "GH" ||
    $country_code == "SN" ||
    $country_code == "TN" ||
    $country_code == "IN" ||
    $country_code == "ID" ||
    $country_code == "KE" ||
    $country_code == "CN" ||
    $country_code == "CI" ||
    $country_code == "ZA" ||
    $country_code == "DZ" ||
    $country_code == "RU"
) {
```